# css two rows 1 column box layout

Tags: css, flexbox

I've been working on a two row and 1 column layout with flexbox, I'm using flexbox because I don't think css2.1 can fill the remainding space for box-B. In my example of my jsFiddle, I can't get box-C to shift up on the right hand side and also I can't get box-B to flex vertically and fill the contents can someone please help me with this layout

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/fccRD/3/)

[image]
[image]

```
#container {
    background-color:red;
    width:100%; height:100%
}

#three-box-layout {
    display:flex;
    display:-ms-flex; 
    display:-webkit-flexbox; 
    display:-moz-flex; 
    height:100%;
    -ms-flex-direction:column;
    -webkit-flex-direction:column
}

.shuffle-box {

}
#box-a {
    background-color:#f601ff; -ms-flex-order:1; -webkit-flex-order:1;
    margin-right:30%;   
}
#box-b {
    -ms-flex:3;
    -webkit-flex:3;
    -moz-flex:3;
    flex:3;

    background-color:#37fe02;
    margin-right:30%;
}
#three-box-layout #box-c {
    -ms-flex:3;
    -webkit-flex:3;
    -moz-flex:3;
    flex:3;

    background-color:#02effe; 

    margin-left:70%; float:right;

}


<div id="container">
    <div id="three-box-layout">
        <div id="box-a" class="shuffle-box">
            <div style="height:425px; background-color:pink">A</div>                
        </div>
        <div id="box-b">B</div>
        <div id="box-c">C</div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: When you say `Max-height: 425px` I assume you mean that up until 425px, it should only expand to the height of it's contents. Is that correct?

Comment: Yeah that's right I used an extra div till fill that space because it will contain something

Comment: Your JS fiddle has one too many closing div tags, and I'm not sure what it should be instead. Can you fix it?

Comment: It has to be in this html layout because it changes to a different layout when the browser changes

Comment: I tidy'd up my code it looks fine to me

Comment: are the 2 columns both fixed at 50% width?

Comment: yeah they can be for this example

Comment: possible duplicate of [css three box layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21424907/css-three-box-layout)

Comment: Don't repost questions.  If your original question was closed, edit it so that it fits the SO standards and can be reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with CSS tables (Flexbox isn't necessary)

**Resize the browser to see the media queries in action!**

[**FIDDLE1**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xgr3k/4/) (little content) / [**FIDDLE2**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xgr3k/6/) (lots of content)

### Markup

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row1">
        <div>A</div>
        <div></div> /* give this div table cell 50% width on wide screens */
    </div>
    <div class="row2">
        <div>B</div>
        <div>C</div>
    </div>
</div>

CSS
--

.container {
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
    display:table;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
.row1 {
    display:table-row;
    max-height: 425px;
    background: pink;
}
.row1 div {
    display:table-cell;
    width:50%;
}
.row2 {
    display:table-row;
    height: 100%;
}
.row2 div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
    background: green;
}
.row2 div + div {
    background: aqua;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
    .row1 {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .row1 div + div {
        display: none;
    }
    .row2 div {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .row2 div + div {
        position: static;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok so that kinda works but my main goal is to have it change box-b and boc to two different positions. when the browser minimizes to 1024px.  I'll update my example to toshow how I want it to look.

Comment: have a look at my updated picture and see if you can make it do that

Comment: so I got it to look like this http://jsfiddle.net/Xgr3k/3/ and that's fine how do I change it to the other layout that I need

Comment: Yeah that's what I was looking for thanks heaps. I just want to know what does the + sign mean in CSS - div + div