# Simple CSS alignment code

Tags: css, position, css-float

I'm trying to create a log in but cant lay it out properly and not too sure why. jsfiddle explains better how I want it to look. I thought it may have been something to do with missing **float:right;** on the button but that didn't seem to do anything

http://jsfiddle.net/6RS65/3/

Thanks!

HTML

```
    <span>
        <i></i>
        <input id="Username" name="Username" type="text" value="Log in button to the left ------->">
    </span>

    <span>
        <i></i>
            <input id="Password" name="Password" type="password">
    </span>

    <span>
        <input class="login" type="submit" name="login" value="Log In">
    </span>

</form>
```

CSS

```
#lr_login {
width:320px;
height:auto;
background-color: #3c92ac;
}
#lr_login span {
padding: 10px;
font-size: 14px;
display: flex;
width: 300px;
}
#lr_login input {
margin:0;
width:180px;
}
#lr_login input.login {
float: right;
width: 60px;
background-color: #388299;
border: none;
-webkit-border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
height: 75px;
}
#lr_login span i {
width: 35px;
height: 30px;
background-color: #6ab5ce;
color: white;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
.left {
float:left;
}
.right {
float:right;
}
}
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve and what is the problem?

Comment: I want the login button to float to the right of the username and password input boxes

Comment: as you are using flex try [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21444149/css-two-rows-1-column-box-layout)

Comment: All your spans (around the boxes and around the button) are as wide as the form box, so no wonder they wont fit next to each other.

Comment: That's a good point, however I have #lr_login input.login {width: 60px; } Wouldnt that override that span to make the width smaller? @GolezTrol

Comment: No, because that applies to the input, not to the span around it.

Comment: Actually, since all the sizes in this box are so much fixed, you might just give the box (the form or div around it) a fixed size and `position: relative` and just position everything in it using absolute positioning. Easiest solution for widgets like this.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help guys, I'll also give that flex post a read =)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the display:flex on spans. Change it to display:block and give your input button a margin-top: -85px;

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

[Check this out](http://jsfiddle.net/6RS65/4/)

```
.clearfix:after {
content: "";
display: table;
clear: both;
}
#lr_login {
width:320px;
height:auto;
background-color: #3c92ac;
}
#lr_login span {
padding: 10px;
font-size: 14px;
display: block;
width: 300px;
}
#lr_login input {
margin:0;
float:left;
width:88%;
height:24px;
}
#lr_login input.login {
float: right;
width: 60px;
background-color: #388299;
border: none;
-webkit-border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
height: 75px;
}
#lr_login span i {
width: 10%;
height: 30px;
background-color: #6ab5ce;
color: white;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
float:left;
}
```